# How to execute R code on client side from restful service?

Tags: java, angularjs, r, database, rest

I have written a rest service which is on the server. Once the client open the UI(in angular), he will enter a name in a textbox. If the record for the name are present on DB(on server), it will fetch the record. But it the record is not present it has to execute a R code on client machine and send back the result back to UI and store it in DB. 
How to implement it. can I somehow send the R code on the client machine in run time, and it will execute it there and send back to UI. There can be multiple client accessing the appliction at same time. Each client machine has R installed.